# (Vue) Axios API call doesnt work when using docker networking hostname

Tags: docker, vue.js, networking, docker-compose, axios

I have created a containerised web app.

The front end is running VueJS in one container on port 8080 and the back end is using flask in a separate container and is running on port 5000.

I have set up a docker compose file to spin up both containers

```
version: '3'

services:
    front-end:
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: front.Dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - DataVolume:/app/confgen-plus/src/assets/Downloads
        ports:
            - 8080:8080

    back-end:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: back.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - DataVolume:/app/confgen-plus/src/assets/Downloads

volumes: 
    DataVolume:
        driver: local
```

Once I have spun up the containers, I am able to successfully access the front-end UI by going to: `http://localhost:8080`

On the home page I have a button which when pressed runs the following code:

```
fetchData: function(){
            this.$axios.get('http://back-end:5000/templates',{
                headers:{
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Accept, Content-Type',

                }
            }).then((response)=>{
                this.templates = response.data
            }
            );
```

The API call is addressed to `back-end:5000/templates`. 'back-end' is the service name given to the back-end container in the docker compose file which should also be the host name automatically assigned to the back-end container in the docker virtual network.

The code above takes the JSON data found at /templates on the back-end and assigns it to the data variable called 'templates'. I then use 2 way binding to display the contents of the JSON file on the front end UI by simply using:

`{{ templates }}`

However with the setup shown above this fails and I am not sure why. I have tested a few things to narrow down the problem:

First I exposed the backend on port 5000 and mapped this to port 5000 on the host machine. I then ammended the code above to address the API call to `http://localhost:5000/templates`. This allowed me to test if the error was somewhere in the front end code. However when I tested the above, it worked successfully showing there was no error here.

Next I used docker exec to enter the front end container and tested if the virtual docker network was correctly set up. I used the following command: `curl http://back-end:5000/test`
The /test endpoint just returns a string which confirms if the back-end is loaded correctly. I got a successful return. I also used the command `curl http://back-end:5000/templates` to see If I would get back the JSON data that was meant to be called by the front end. Once again the test was successful. So this proves that the virtual network is also correct and the front-end container should be able to access the back-end container via the hostname back-end:5000/templates.

If i share the error from the console in the browser:
[image]
You can see that the call is going to the correct address but there is an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `get` call is coming from your browser, not the front-end container.  Since the browser's outside of Docker it doesn't know anything about the Docker-internal DNS system.  You need to use the host name of the system running the container (or `localhost` in a single-host development environment) and the published `ports:` of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are using `docker-compose` version `~3` you must add the aliases for networking.

See [docker-compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)

I think it will work like this:

```
services:
  front-end:
    build: 
        context: ./
        dockerfile: front.Dockerfile
    volumes: 
        - DataVolume:/app/confgen-plus/src/assets/Downloads
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - front-end

back-end:
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: back.Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - DataVolume:/app/confgen-plus/src/assets/Downloads
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - back-end
```

Comment: Im not sure that the issue is with the host names. As I stated above, i tested that the containers can reach each other by the host names by docker exec into the container then sending a curl request to the back-end host name

Comment: :(  I had a similar problem when using docker-compose and I really went mad with it. That was my solution. After including it, everything worked. Not sure if it would solve it in your case, I just tried to remark that version 3 of compose was slightly different from previous ones.

Comment: Okay well I will try it anyway

Comment: Compose will create these by default for you; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details.  For calls _between containers_ `front-end` and `back-end` will work as host names without any modification.  The problem here is that the call is coming from the browser, not a container.

Comment: As @DavidMaze Also says, as you are executing "from the browser", you need to be able to know this remote host in order to be able to reach it, also. In my case the issue was between backend and mongo. So, maybe doing: 

1.- Adding the host external ip as a new env variable for the nginx 
2.- Read the variable from Javascript
3-  Modify links to dinamically use the IP value you obtained from env variables.

I also did similar approach to protect my internal docker, making a proxy server (with express.js) which redirects to my internal container, exposing only needed data.